# formations of union of sets

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

How do I get the formations generated by the union of sets?

Practical example
As an example of this calculation,if we denote the four sets:

```
S1 = {1, 4} , S2 = {2, 5} , S3 = {1, 3, 5} , S4 = {2, 3, 4}
```

then the formations associated with the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} are the 4 odd formations (namely, the four unions of the sets {S1,S2,S3}, {S1,S2,S4},
{S1,S3,S4} and {S2,S3,S4}) and the 2 even formations (namely, the two
unions of the sets {S3,S4} and {S1,S2,S3,S4}).

How do I get odd and even formations generated by the union of sets?

Comment: I do not know what a "formation" is, can you provide a reference or link where this is defined, or is it your own terminology? And are you sure this is a question for Mathematica (as opposed to mathematics) stack exchange? If you are asking for Mathematica code, please include what you have tried already.

Comment: @user293787 Yes, this term is used in graph theory and I'm looking for a code for it in mathmatica. I have also been asked by these sources:
1- Definition and example on page 82
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-71797-5
2- Definition and example on page 45
  https://books.google.iq/books?id=4QjpMocMLnQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=RELIABILITY+AND+MAINTENANCE+NETWORKS+AND+SYSTEMS&hl=ar&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=RELIABILITY%20AND%20NET%20MAINTORANCE 20SYSTEMS&f=false

Answer (score 5):

I gather that a formation is like a covering set. I would probably define a general function like this:

```
Formations[count_, target_, parts_] :=
  Select[Subsets[parts, {count}], SubsetQ[Flatten[#], target] &]
```

So, for example

```
Formations[2, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {S1, S2, S3, S4}]
```

returns `{{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 4}}}`.

```
Formations[4, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {S1, S2, S3, S4}]
```

returns `{{{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 4}}}`.

If you wanted the "names" of each set, you could do something like this:

```
Formations[3, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {S1, S2, S3, S4}] /. {S1 -> "S1", S2 -> "S2", S3 -> "S3", S4 -> "S4"}
```

which returns `{{"S1", "S2", "S3"}, {"S1", "S2", "S4"}, {"S1", "S3", "S4"}, {"S2", "S3", "S4"}}`.

This would probably get expensive for large sets.